# error eip170 when i try to deploy UniswapV2Router02 smart contract

Tags: solidity, uniswap

when i deploy UniswapV2Router02 smart contract i  get error
creation of UniswapV2Router02 errored: Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32003,"message":"sender region is blocked as appearing on the SDN or other legally prohibited list"}}'","id":5746910245801820}

Comment: Looks like the issue is related to your node provider blocking your IP. Try different provider or send the deploying transaction using a VPN.